# How to parse an HTTP Request in Java?

Tags: java, http, httpwebrequest, http-headers, httprequest

When implementing a proxy server, I get an HTTP request as a string, such as this one:

> GET http://localhost:54321/x HTTP/1.1
>
> Host: localhost:54321
>
> Cache-Control: no-cache

Is there a built-in class to parse this request?

Comment: The "built-in" classes to parse this (such as classes implementing [`HttpServletRequest`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html)) are part of Java Enterprise Edition and are usually integrated into a web server, which means they are not suitable for your purpose.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know anything about built-in support for such parsing. If you really need such parser, you can check out this lib: http://hc.apache.org/index.html

Here's detailed example: http://www.mail-archive.com/httpclient-user@jakarta.apache.org/msg04070.html

Answer (score 1):

if "built in" means the JDK I am pretty sure there is no class that does you bidding.

As Lukas says, HttpComponents might be of help. Even if there is no class that does exactly what you want there is code available to look at how they do it.

It is not very hard to implement this yourself though.
Some string splitting will do the trick.