# Parsing HTTP requests

Tags: java, httprequest

When dealing with the requests of type

```
GET /someFile.txt HTTP/1.1
```

Is there a library that will help you find /someFile.txt with ease, or is it common to manually split and parse things? No big deal, just wondering.

```
message.split("\\s+")[1] // works but just looks silly
```

Comment: What programming language? What environment?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5625388/how-to-parse-an-http-request-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on the server (servlet container) side, `HttpServletRequest.getPathInfo` should do the job.

http://goo.gl/gRW7H