# Java SE - a small web server program

Tags: java

I am just curious how to implement a small server program in Java SE?

The program is listening on port 80 and ready to retrieve an InputStream object, but is there any function I can use to convert an InputStream into an HttpRequest object (something like Servlet)?

After that, how can I craft an HttpResponse object and send the data back to the browser?

Conclusively, I am just looking any framework that can help me parse the HTTP format into an object, or from an object into an HTTP response stream.

(I know Java EE will be the better solution, I just want to test something on Java SE)

Comment: If you wish to understand what that framework would do behind the scenes, Google for the structure of HTTP. Or rather, let a browser make a request, and try printing the contents of the stream that you have on the Java side.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Look no further than [Jetty](http://jetty.codehaus.org/jetty/) in this case. It is written for exactly that purpouse - embedding an HTTP server into your application. But probably won't get you an HttpRequest object, but perhaps something similar that should suit your needs.

Answer (score 3):

If you've got the InputStream and just need to process the request/format a response, have a look at [Apache HttpComponents](http://hc.apache.org/index.html)

For more info see this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5625479/416627

Answer (score 2):

A really lightweight servlet container, which is very suitable for [embedding](http://winstone.sourceforge.net/#embedding), is [Winstone](http://winstone.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: @jderda: AFAIK it's still being actively used by [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) at least.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a Servlet implementation, have a look at Tomcat: http://tomcat.apache.org/

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for something very lightweight and flexible you might want to look at Netty

https://netty.io/Documentation/WebHome

Personally I found it a little hard to get started with but once the initial hurdle was overcome it was quite powerful.